# Number of ordered triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $abc=n$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, parity

I am trying to investigate the situation above, or more weakly I am wondering about the parity of this number depending on $n$.

This came about because I know that the number of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ with $ab=n$ is just another way of saying the number of divisors, which is odd $\iff $ $n$ is square.

Initially I thought the number would be odd $\iff $ $n$ is a cube, (true for $n$ prime and $n=pq$ with $p,q$ prime from my tests), but I then realised it is odd for $n=4,\; n=6$ too, unless I've miscounted somewhere. Maybe it is always odd.

I believe it entirely depends on how many $a$ are such that $a^2b=n$, because these each give $3$ triples, or $1$ if $a=b$. In other words, the number of square *factors*.

I am stuck on how to count this though, even considering prime decomposition.

I don't think this can be related to *weak compositions* because the triples are ordered.

---

Am I overcomplicating this?

Comment: This is usually called $d_3(n)$ and is another multiplicative function (in the arithmetic sense) so its value is determined on prime powers where it is easy to find (hint: fix a divisor $m$ and notice that then you get $(a,b,m), abm=n$ iff $ab = \frac{m}{n}$ The formula should be quadratic with denominator $2$ in the power of the prime so the parity will come from the exponent of the prime powers modulo $4$ this time so it will be odd if all exponents are $0,1$ modulo $4$

Comment: for $n=4$ there are 6 triples $(1,1,4),(1,2,2),(2,1,2), (4,1,1), (1,4,1), (2,2,1)$ so it is not odd

Comment: As shown below, if $R(n)$ is the number of triples $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{N}^3$ such that $abc=n$, $$\frac{\mathbb{P}[R(n)\text{ is even}]}{\mathbb{P}[R(n)\text{ is odd}]}\approx \frac{13}{25}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $n$ can be factored as $p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k^{\alpha_k}$, the number of triples $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{N}^3$ such that $abc=n$ is given by the number of ways to distribute $p_1^{\alpha_1}$ among $a,b,c$ and so on, i.e. by

$$ \prod_{h=1}^{k}r_3(\alpha_h) $$
where
$$\begin{eqnarray*} r_3(m) &=& \left|\{(u,v,w)\in\mathbb{N}^3:u+v+w=m\}\right| \\&=&[x^m]\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}=\frac{(m+1)(m+2)}{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
by stars and bars. This leads to
$$ \prod_{h=1}^{\omega(n)}\frac{(\nu_{p_h}(n)+1)(\nu_{p_h}(n)+2)}{2} $$
which is odd *iff* all its factors are odd, i.e. iff all the exponents in the factorization of $n$ are of the form $4k$ or $4k+1$. It follows that
$$ R(n)=\left|\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{N}^3:abc=n\}\right| $$
is always even, unless $n$ is the product between a fourth power and a square-free number. The density of these numbers in $\mathbb{N}$ is $\frac{\zeta(4)}{\zeta(2)}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{15}}\approx\frac{25}{38}$. Notice that for $n=4$ we have *six* triples, namely $(4,1,1),(1,4,1),(1,1,4),(1,2,2),(2,1,2),(2,2,1)$. For $n=6$ we have *nine* triples, given by the cyclic permutations of $(6,1,1)$ and the permutations of $(1,2,3)$. Indeed $6$ is a square-free number. It is also interesting to point out that
$$ R(n) = \sum_{d\mid n}\tau(d) = (\tau * 1)(n) $$
is a multiplicative function whose associated Dirichlet series equals
$$ f(s)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{R(n)}{n^s}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\tau(n)}{n^s} = \zeta(s)^3. $$
The RHS behaves like $\frac{1}{(s-1)^3}$ in a right neighbourhood of $s=1$, hence the average order of $R(n)$ is $\frac{1}{2}\log^2(n)+O(\log n)$.

Comment: Thank you, unsure of how I miscounted $n=4$. The probability is very neat, though I don't think I have the knowledge to understand where the $\zeta$'s come from.

Comment: @user111064: the fact that the density of square-free numbers is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}=\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}$ is fairly well-known. Every number of the form *squarefree* $\times$ *fourth power* can be decomposed in a unique way into its factors, hence we just have to add the densities of *squarefree*, $16\times$ *squarefree*, $81\times$ *squarefree* etcetera, leading to $\frac{\zeta(4)}{\zeta(2)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain this to you with an example.
Suppose we need to find all ordered triplets for $(a,b,c)$ for $abc=200$
Now you know,  $200=5^2\cdot2^3$
Now let

> $a=2^{p_1}\cdot 5^{q_1}$ ;
>
> $b=2^{p_2}\cdot 5^{q_2}$;
>
> $c=2^{p_3}\cdot 5^{q_3}$

Since $abc=200$ we can confer ${p_1} + {p_2} + {p_3}=3$ ;
Also ${q_1} + {q_2} + {q_3}=2$

Now you just need to figure out in how many ways $p_1$, $p_2$ ,$p_3$ can be chosen so that sum is 3 and ${q_1}$, ${q_2}$ ,${q_3}$ be chosen so that the sum is $2$ now using stars and bars method ( see here https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/)

We can easily figure out the answer that is

> $=$ ${3+3-1}\choose {3}$ $\cdot$ ${2+3-1} \choose {2} $ $=60$. Also note that since signs can be interchanged in $4$ ways that is $(+, - ,-)$ $; (-, + ,-) ;$ $(- , - , +) ;$ $(+ , + , +)$ the final answer would be $60\cdot 4$ $=240$

Can you figure out now the basic method of solving these type of problems?

Comment: I see, so (neglecting sign), if $n=\prod_i p_i^{\alpha_i}$ the number is $\prod_i \binom{\alpha_i+3-1}{3-1}=\prod_i \frac{1}{2}(\alpha_i+1)(\alpha_i+2)$ which is only odd iff $\alpha_i\neq 2, 3\mod{4}$, in line with the other answer.